# Cross domain file is loading but with syntax error

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, cross-domain, getjson

I am trying to get a file through jquery from cross domain the code is

```
$.getJSON('http://tzook.info/bot/t.htm?callback=?', function(jsonp) {
alert('loaded');
});
```

​But the error on console is

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://tzook.info/bot/t.htm?callback=jsonp1353261653582". jquery-1.4.2.js:5093
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Why is this error.

[Js Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfvKm/2635/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are trying to do is not possible if you are making a cross domain call because of [security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Only JSONP is an exception and your response doesn't look site JSON.

**SOLUTION:**

Either use JSONP response or use backend proxy.

Comment: Updated answer to include solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use simple ajax request and then decode result. And link http://tzook.info/bot/t.htm?callback=? get html ! not json

Comment: var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );

Answer (score 0):

You can't use char `?` in the url, it is used to separate paramaters

Try something like this to remove your error :

```
$.getJSON('http://tzook.info/bot/t.htm?callback=test', function(jsonp) {
alert('loaded');
});
```

Comment: Of course you are a crossdomain problem if you are not on the same "domain", I have just explained the syntax error

Comment: how i can load html from cross domain

Comment: You can't. There is some exception about JSONP returned data, but you can't retrieve html from another domain.